# How to calculate rotation axis and angle?

Tags: math, 3d, openframeworks

I am trying to rotate a model in 3D so that it faces the right direction. The rotation I want is fairly trivial and can be broken down into two steps:

1. Rotate the model 90 degrees on its x-axis.
2. Rotate the model 180 degrees on its z-axis (relative to the first rotation).

The way to set a model's rotation in the framework I'm using (openFrameworks) is by calling its setRotation method. This method takes an angle, as well as floats x, y and z that specify the axis of rotation. How do I calculate the axis of rotation and angle for this particular rotation? I can't rotate the model two times sequentially because any call to setRotation overwrites previous rotations.

Please let me know if I can provide more information or clarity.

EDIT: In case anyone has the same question, this post [helped me a lot](http://voidinit.blogspot.com/2012/01/quaternions-and-openframeworks.html).

Comment: Link to post is broken. This is why there's a preference to actually include/summarize the content on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

weird that you can not apply more then one transform ... maybe you just use wrong function but anyway:

If you have direct access to transform matrix (or by get,set)

1. google for transform matrices if you do not have the knowledge

   - I suspect you are using 4x4 homogenous cartesian transform matrices
   - [transform matrix anatomy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216549/2521214)
2. generate first rotation matrix and store it to `M1`

   - can use the setRotation for that
3. generate second rotation matrix and store it to `M2`
4. multiply them `M=M1*M2`
5. use this `M` instead of setRotation

If yo do not have the direct access to transform matrix and have to use just the setRotation

- in that case you have to use quaternion which is the 4D vector you call the setRotation with
- google for quaternion math and find the application of 2 rotations
- I do not use them so I can not help with that but there are also equations out there
- which converts 3x3 rotation matrix into quaternion and back
- so you can still use the algorithm above
- obtain `M`
- extract the rotation matrix from it (it is just sub matrix you omit last row and column)
- compute quaternion from it
- and call setRotation with the result