# How to show visible part of planar world rendered with 3D perspective on topside 2D minimap?

Tags: c++, opengl, math, perspective

**Prologue**

This **Q&A** is a remake of:

- [How to highlight 3D perspective camera view (frustrum) on topside 2D minimap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52345064/2521214)

which was closed (and failed first reopening cycle) due to lack of info and no response of the original author. However I think this is an interesting question though so I decided to Ask&Answer this myself (this time with all the needed specs).

**Question**

Let assume our world is a uniform rectangular square grid (represented by 2D array of tiles) mapped on a plane (let say plane **XY** (`Z=0.0`) for simplicity) and is rendered with perspective projection. like this:

[image: preview]

How to map the perspective frustrum (visible part of the map/plane) to the red colored polygonal shape on the minimap ?

To be more universal let assume this as input:

- plane (`Z=0.0`) defined as start point `p0` and two basis vectors `du,dv` which maps the 2D map array of tiles to 3D ...
- `ModelView` matrix and `Perspective` matrix used

And wanted output:

- 4 point polygon (on minimap) representing the visible part of out plane

Limitations (to more or less match the original question):

- use **C++**
- old style **OpenGL** (**GL,GLU**)
- no 3th party lib for vector/matrix math

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what we want is to obtain the 4 intersection points between our plane (`Z=0.0`) and camera frustrum. So the idea is to cast 4 rays (one for each edge of frustrum) from the camera focal point and simply compute the ray/plane intersection. As the plane is `Z=0.0` the intersection point has `Z=0.0` too so the intersection is quite easy to compute.

1. **Cast ray for each corner/edge**

   from camera focal point to screen corner (in screen space)

   [image: frustrum]

   and convert it to world global coordinates (by reverting perspective and using inverse modelview matrix it is described later). The ray should be in form:

   ```
   p(t) = p + dp*t
   ```

   where `p` is the focal point and `dp` is direction vector (does not need to be normalized)
2. **compute the intersection with XY plane (`Z=0.0`)**

   As the `z=0.0` then:

   ```
   0 = p.z + dp.z*t
   t = -p.z/dp.z
   ```

   so we can compute the intersection point directly.
3. **convert 3D intersection points to `u,v` inside map**

   for that simple dot product is enough. So if `p` is our intersection point then:

   ```
   u = dot(p-p0,du)
   v = dot(p-p0,dv)
   ```

   where `u,v` are coordinates in our 2D map array or minimap. In case your `u,v` are axis aligned then you can use directly `(p.x-p0.x,p.y-p0.y)` without any dot product

**How to convert point `p` from camera coordinates to global world coordinates:**

1. **revert perspective**

   first obtain perspective matrix parameters

   ```
   double per[16],zNear,zFar,fx,fy;
   glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,per);
   zFar =0.5*per[14]*(1.0-((per[10]-1.0)/(per[10]+1.0)));
   zNear=zFar*(per[10]+1.0)/(per[10]-1.0);
   fx=per[0];
   fy=per[5];
   ```

   This will give you the frustrums near and far planes and scaling for x,y axises. Now reverting perspective is simply inverting the perspective divide like this:

   ```
   p[1]*=(-p[2]/fy);                   // apply inverse of perspective
   p[0]*=(-p[2]/fx);
   ```

   The `znear` and `zfar` are needed for casting the rays. For more info see:

   - [depth buffer got by glReadPixels is always 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51130948/2521214)
2. **global world coordinates**

   simply use inverse of `ModelView` matrix on our `p`. So first obtain the matrix:

   ```
   double cam[16];
   glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,cam);
   ```

   As inverse you can use my [matrix_inv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42293434/2521214) so now the final step is:

   ```
   p = Inverse(cam)*p;
   ```

   but do not forget that `p` must be homogenuous so `(x,y,z,1)` for points and `(x,y,z,0)` for vectors.

Look here if you lack the background knowledge or need vector/matrix math:

- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

**Here Small C++ example of this:**

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void matrix_mul_vector(double *c,double *a,double *b)
    {
    double q[3];
    q[0]=(a[ 0]*b[0])+(a[ 4]*b[1])+(a[ 8]*b[2])+(a[12]);
    q[1]=(a[ 1]*b[0])+(a[ 5]*b[1])+(a[ 9]*b[2])+(a[13]);
    q[2]=(a[ 2]*b[0])+(a[ 6]*b[1])+(a[10]*b[2])+(a[14]);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) c[i]=q[i];
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void  matrix_inv(double *a,double *b) // a[16] = Inverse(b[16])
    {
    double x,y,z;
    // transpose of rotation matrix
    a[ 0]=b[ 0];
    a[ 5]=b[ 5];
    a[10]=b[10];
    x=b[1]; a[1]=b[4]; a[4]=x;
    x=b[2]; a[2]=b[8]; a[8]=x;
    x=b[6]; a[6]=b[9]; a[9]=x;
    // copy projection part
    a[ 3]=b[ 3];
    a[ 7]=b[ 7];
    a[11]=b[11];
    a[15]=b[15];
    // convert origin: new_pos = - new_rotation_matrix * old_pos
    x=(a[ 0]*b[12])+(a[ 4]*b[13])+(a[ 8]*b[14]);
    y=(a[ 1]*b[12])+(a[ 5]*b[13])+(a[ 9]*b[14]);
    z=(a[ 2]*b[12])+(a[ 6]*b[13])+(a[10]*b[14]);
    a[12]=-x;
    a[13]=-y;
    a[14]=-z;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void draw_map()
    {
    int i,j;
    double u,v,p[3],dp[3];

    // here 3D view must be already set (modelview,projection)
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    // [draw 3D map]
    const int n=30;                 // map size
    double p0[3]={0.0,0.0,0.0};     // map start point
    double du[3]={1.0,0.0,0.0};     // map u step (size of grid = 1.0 )
    double dv[3]={0.0,1.0,0.0};     // map v step (size of grid = 1.0 )
    glColor3f(0.5,0.7,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for (j=0;j<=n;j++)
        {
        for (i=0;i<3;i++) p[i]=p0[i]+(double(j)*du[i])+(double(0)*dv[i]); glVertex3dv(p);
        for (i=0;i<3;i++) p[i]=p0[i]+(double(j)*du[i])+(double(n)*dv[i]); glVertex3dv(p);
        for (i=0;i<3;i++) p[i]=p0[i]+(double(0)*du[i])+(double(j)*dv[i]); glVertex3dv(p);
        for (i=0;i<3;i++) p[i]=p0[i]+(double(n)*du[i])+(double(j)*dv[i]); glVertex3dv(p);
        }
    glEnd();

    // [compute trapeze points]
    double cam[16],per[16],pt[4][3],zNear,zFar,fx,fy;
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,per); // obtain matrices
    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,cam);
    matrix_inv(cam,cam);
    zFar =0.5*per[14]*(1.0-((per[10]-1.0)/(per[10]+1.0)));
    zNear=zFar*(per[10]+1.0)/(per[10]-1.0);
    fx=per[0];
    fy=per[5];
    for (j=0;j<4;j++)                       // 4 corners
        {
        for (i=0;i<3;i++) dp[i]=0.0;        // cast ray from camera focus dp
        if (j==0) { p[0]=-1.0; p[1]=-1.0; } // to screen corner p
        if (j==1) { p[0]=-1.0; p[1]=+1.0; }
        if (j==2) { p[0]=+1.0; p[1]=+1.0; }
        if (j==3) { p[0]=+1.0; p[1]=-1.0; }
        p[2]=zNear;                         // start position at screen plane
        p[1]*=(-p[2]/fy);                   // apply inverse of perspective
        p[0]*=(-p[2]/fx);
        // transform to worlds global coordinates
        matrix_mul_vector( p,cam, p);
        matrix_mul_vector(dp,cam,dp);
        // compute intersection of ray and XY plane (z=0) as pt[j] (i exploited the fact that the intersection have z=0.0 for arbitrary plane it would be a bit more complicated)
        for (i=0;i<3;i++) dp[i]=p[i]-dp[i];
        u=p[2]/dp[2];
        if (u<0.0) u=(p[2]-zFar)/dp[2];     // no intersection means "infinite" visibility
        for (i=0;i<3;i++) pt[j][i]=p[i]-(u*dp[i]);
        u=0.0;
        }

    // [draw 2D minimap]
    GLint vp0[4];
    GLint vp1[4]={10,10,150,150};           // minimap position and size ppixels[
    double q0[2]={-1.0,-1.0 };              // minimap start point
    double eu[2]={2.0/double(n),0.0};       // minimap u step
    double ev[2]={0.0,2.0/double(n)};       // minimap v step

    // set 2D view for minimap
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT,vp0);
    glViewport(vp1[0],vp1[1],vp1[2],vp1[3]);

    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);                 // clear background
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    for (i=0;i<2;i++) p[i]=q0[i]+(double(0)*eu[i])+(double(0)*ev[i]); glVertex2dv(p);
    for (i=0;i<2;i++) p[i]=q0[i]+(double(n)*eu[i])+(double(0)*ev[i]); glVertex2dv(p);
    for (i=0;i<2;i++) p[i]=q0[i]+(double(n)*eu[i])+(double(n)*ev[i]); glVertex2dv(p);
    for (i=0;i<2;i++) p[i]=q0[i]+(double(0)*eu[i])+(double(n)*ev[i]); glVertex2dv(p);
    glEnd();

    glColor3f(0.15,0.15,0.15);              // grid
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for (j=0;j<=n;j++)
        {
        for (i=0;i<2;i++) p[i]=q0[i]+(double(j)*eu[i])+(double(0)*ev[i]); glVertex2dv(p);
        for (i=0;i<2;i++) p[i]=q0[i]+(double(j)*eu[i])+(double(n)*ev[i]); glVertex2dv(p);
        for (i=0;i<2;i++) p[i]=q0[i]+(double(0)*eu[i])+(double(j)*ev[i]); glVertex2dv(p);
        for (i=0;i<2;i++) p[i]=q0[i]+(double(n)*eu[i])+(double(j)*ev[i]); glVertex2dv(p);
        }
    glEnd();

    glColor3f(0.5,0.5,0.5);                 // border of minimap
    glLineWidth(2.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (i=0;i<2;i++) p[i]=q0[i]+(double(0)*eu[i])+(double(0)*ev[i]); glVertex2dv(p);
    for (i=0;i<2;i++) p[i]=q0[i]+(double(n)*eu[i])+(double(0)*ev[i]); glVertex2dv(p);
    for (i=0;i<2;i++) p[i]=q0[i]+(double(n)*eu[i])+(double(n)*ev[i]); glVertex2dv(p);
    for (i=0;i<2;i++) p[i]=q0[i]+(double(0)*eu[i])+(double(n)*ev[i]); glVertex2dv(p);
    glEnd();
    glLineWidth(1.0);

    // 2D minimap render of the pt[]
    glColor3f(0.7,0.1,0.1);                 // trapeze
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
        // get u,v from pt[j]
        for (i=0;i<3;i++) p[i]=pt[j][i]-p0[i];
        for (u=0.0,i=0;i<3;i++) u+=p[i]*du[i];
        for (v=0.0,i=0;i<3;i++) v+=p[i]*dv[i];
        // convert to 2D position and render
        for (i=0;i<2;i++) p[i]=q0[i]+(u*eu[i])+(v*ev[i]); glVertex2dv(p);
        }
    glEnd();

    // restore 3D view
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();
    glViewport(vp0[0],vp0[1],vp0[2],vp0[3]);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And preview:

[image: preview]

As you can see we need just matrix*vector multiplication and pseudo inverse matrix functions for this (all others like `dot,+,-` are really simple and directly encoded as inline code) and both are simple enough  to directly implement it in code so no need for **GLM** or similar lib.

Also I was too lazy to clip the 4 point polygon to minimap size so instead I used `glViewport` which did it for me.

**Here Win32 BDS2006 VCL/C++/OpenGL1.0 Demo:**

- [Demo Source+Binary](https://ulozto.net/!Zhg1pimtK1Fa/gl-sqr-grid-zip)

Just select **slow download** and enter the validation code from image. It does not use any 3th party libs other than **GL,GLU**. The camera is static so just add keyboard/mouse events to your liking. If you want to port this to your environment just mimic the events behavior and ignore the **VCL** stuff.

The OpenGL init is done based on this:

- [simple complete GL+VAO/VBO+GLSL+shaders example in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214)

I just removed the **GLEW,GLSL** and **VAO** stuff from it.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the approach presented here is based on the assumption that the projection matrix describes a centered perspective projection and will not work with any other kind of projection. A much simpler and more general approach would be to just take the eight corners of the view frustum, which can simply be identified by their clip-space coordinates (±1, ±1, ±1, 1), transform them with the inverse ModelViewProjection matrix, divide by w and you have the world-space coordinates of the eight corners of the view frustum; works with any projection that can be put into matrix form…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel yep the code expects `gluPerspective` kind of matrix.